# jquery in each loop append content to specific class

Tags: jquery, html, class, append, each

how I can append content regarding to specific class in thr jquery in each loop.

I want to append in the each strong>Hello for every **ppp** class.
but this code don't working `$(item)(.'ppp').append( "<strong>Hello</strong>" );`

here is the complete example

```js
$('.testimonial').each(function(index, item) {
  var im = $('img').attr('src');
  var iml = im.lenght;
  var divpp = $('.ppp');
  if (parseInt($(item).data('index')) > 0) {

    $(item).html('Testimonial ' + (index + 1) +
      '<span class="img-code"><input type="text" value=\'' + im + '\'></span> <br>');
    $(item)(.
      'ppp').append("<strong>Hello</strong>");

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="1">
  Testimonial
  <div class="ppp" style="background-color:purple;"></div>
  <img src="upload/IMG_20160721_143235(1).jpg" class="imgpfad" width="250px">
</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="2">
  Testimonial 2
  <div class="ppp" style="background-color:purple;"></div>
  <img src="upload/IMG_20160721_143235(2).jpg" class="imgpfad" width="250px">

</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="3">
  Testimonial 3
  <img src="upload/IMG_20160721_143235(3).jpg" class="imgpfad" width="250px">
  <div class="ppp"></div>
</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="4">
  Testimonial 4
  <img src="upload/IMG_20160721_143235(4).jpg" class="imgpfad" width="250px">
  <div class="ppp"></div>
</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="5">
  Testimonial 5
  <img src="upload/IMG_20160721_143235(5).jpg" class="imgpfad" width="250px">
  <div class="ppp"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm curious, what do you expect `$(item)(.'ppp')` to do? It's invalid syntax...

Comment: how i can do that   $(item, .'ppp') does not working to

Comment: Needs to be `$(item).find(.'ppp')` but you wipe out everything inside those elements when you do `$(item).html('...')` so there won't be any `.ppp` to find

Comment: It probably also should be `$(item).find('img').attr('src')`. Otherwise you'll get the `src` of the first image every time through the loop.

Comment: also `lenght != length`

Comment: You should put the text `Testimonial 1` in its own `<span>` or `<div>` so you can just set the HTML there without wiping out all the other HTML in the `.testimonial` DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Put the testimonial number in its own `<span>` so you can change its HTML without affecting the rest of the contents of the DIV. And use `.find()` to access other elements in the current DIV in the loop.

You don't need to call `parseInt()` when you use `.data()`. If the data can be parsed as JSON, jQuery will do this automatically.

```js
$('.testimonial').each(function(index, item) {
  var im = $(item).find('img').attr('src');
  var iml = im.length;
  var divpp = $(item).find('.ppp');
  if ($(item).data('index') > 0) {

    $(item).find('.title').html('Testimonial ' + (index + 1) +
      '<span class="img-code"><input type="text" value=\'' + im + '\'></span> <br>');
    divpp.append("<strong>Hello</strong>");

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="1">
  <span class="title">Testimonial</span>
  <div class="ppp" style="background-color:purple;"></div>
  <img src="upload/IMG_20160721_143235(1).jpg" class="imgpfad" width="250px">
</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="2">
  <span class="title">Testimonial 2</span>
  <div class="ppp" style="background-color:purple;"></div>
  <img src="upload/IMG_20160721_143235(2).jpg" class="imgpfad" width="250px">

</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="3">
  <span class="title">Testimonial 3</span>
  <img src="upload/IMG_20160721_143235(3).jpg" class="imgpfad" width="250px">
  <div class="ppp"></div>
</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="4">
  <span class="title">Testimonial 4</span>
  <img src="upload/IMG_20160721_143235(4).jpg" class="imgpfad" width="250px">
  <div class="ppp"></div>
</div>
<div class="testimonial" data-index="5">
  <span class="title">Testimonial 5</span>
  <img src="upload/IMG_20160721_143235(5).jpg" class="imgpfad" width="250px">
  <div class="ppp"></div>
</div>
```